# in powershell Special Variable not working

Tags: excel, powershell

**$_.**

I have an order which includes Excel and Powershell.

[Here you can see the "tags" im working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tu7R.png)

You also may have seen that there are gaps between the 2nd 3rd and 4th. I seem to be having a problem with working these into $_.

```
import-csv -Path C:\Users\admin.kln\Documents\Project\BOSAN_USERS.csv|foreach{
$Firstname = $_.Firstname
$Lastname = $_.Last_Name
$Displayname = $_.Display_Name
Write-Host $Firstname
}
```

Its for now a small script but `$Firstname` gives the outcome of a couple of names below eachother like:

```
Bastian
Frank
Bob
```

`$LastName`, `$Last_Name` or `$Last.Name` All have this outcome:

I dont know how to fix this and it would be really helpfull if someone did know!

Thanks for the help beforehand!

Comment: Please edit the question to include the first few lines of the CSV - it is likely that your problem lies there.

Comment: And @Pba gives the correct answer - I expected that it would be something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Lastname = $_."Last Name"

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer to help other people who are having a similar question :-)

Comment: I _strongly_ urge people who are planning on exporting to CSV for PowerShell to ensure that column headings do _not_ have spaces or "special" characters other than the underscore, specifically because of this problem.

Comment: I got the order, I just carry the orders out :P